# xtrareport Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Estoy tratando de visualizar un reporte en vb.net el cual usa como reporte `Xtrareport` pero el mismo lo hice en un proyecto aparte, cuando intento pasar los parámetros me da este error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Este es el código:

```
Public Sub CreateAndShowReport1(ByVal Codprestamo As String)

    Dim report As XtraReport =  XtraReport.FromFile("F:\J_RAMIREZ\PROYECTOS\Easy Money\Easy Money\Reportes\RptAmortizacion.repx", True)

    report.Parameters("Codempresa").Value = Codempresa
    report.Parameters("Codprestamo").Value = Codprestamo

    Dim printTool As New ReportPrintTool(report)
    printTool.ShowPreviewDialog()

End Sub
```

Comment: prueba a poner una `@` delante de la ruta del fichero. Me parece raro que te funcione así la verdad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema por mi propia cuenta y es que no estaba instanciando el objeto este es el código luego de la modificación

```
    Dim Report as New xtraReport
    Public Sub CreateAndShowReport1(ByVal Codprestamo As String) 
             XtraReport =XtraReport.FromFile("F:\J_RAMIREZ\PROYECTOS\Easy Money\Easy Money\Reportes\RptAmortizacion.repx", True)
 report.Parameters("Codempresa").Value = Codempresa
 report.Parameters("Codprestamo").Value = Codprestamo 
Dim printTool As New ReportPrintTool(report)
 printTool.ShowPreviewDialog() 
        End Sub
```